# Node.js - Requiring mongoose here and there causes redundancy?

Tags: node.js, arguments, mongoose, require, redundancy

I have the following Node.js directory structure.

```
|--app/
   |--app.js
   |--routers/
      |--index.js/
   |--models/
      |--schemas.js
      |--post.js
```

In **app.js**, there's a line likes this `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/' + config.DB_NAME);`. In **schema.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
    , author: String
    , body: String
    , creataAt: { 
        type: Date
        , default: Date.now
    }
});

// other schemas goes here

module.exports.PostSchema = PostSchema;
```

In **post.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , PostSchema = require('./schemas').PostSchema
    , PostModel = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

module.exports = PostModel;
```

And in **index.js**, there might be a line likes this: `var PostModel = require('../models/post');`. All files mentioned above require **mongoose**. The purpose of **schemas.js** is for helping programmers to grasp the schema of the database in a single file. However, I wonder if this implement causes redundancy and cause more overhead, for I require **mongoose** here and there. Should I pass it as an **argument** around?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're only worried about performance, you need not be. As per http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching:

> #### Caching
>
> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to `require('foo')` may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> If you want to have a module execute code multiple times, then export
>   a function, and call that function.

So, you're not actually `requiring` Mongoose each time; rather, each time after the first, the cached Mongoose module is returned.

Comment: Thanks. What else should I concern when requiring things?

Comment: Well, you may not personally be happy with the architecture decisions that result in certain patterns, but that's secondary to the technical issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pay attention when requiring mongoose from linked modules. In the case of mongoose you most often rely on the singleton pattern to get through to the mongodb connection, and the caching mechanism can get in the way of modularity.
I might have done something wrong, but I detailed the issue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687619/node-js-require-do-not-behave-as-expected-when-using-linked-packages